# Vector space and not necessarily equal composition

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

Suppose V is a vector space of dimension n and W$\subseteq L(V,V)$ is a subspace. Suppose $ST,TS$ are both in $W$ for every $S \in L(V,V)$ and for every $T\in W$. Then $W$ $=$ $\{$ $\textbf{0}$  $\}$ or $W=L(V,V)$.

My attempt:

As $W$ is a subspace of $L(V,V)$, it must be of finite dimension hence either $W=L(V,V)$ or not. If equality holds then we are done, so suppose otherwise. Now I must show that $W \subseteq$ $\{$ $\textbf{0}$ $\}$. Let $T$ be arbitrary in $W$. By Assumption $TS,ST$ are in $W$ for every $S \in L(V,V)$.

Im not really sure how to proceed. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following works: Consider the basis $B=\{e_{1},...,e_{n}\}$ and for fixed $1\leq i,j\leq n$, consider the map $X_{i,j}(e_{k})=\delta_{ki}e_{j}$, $k=1,...,n$. Suppose that $T\in W$, $T\ne 0$, say, some entry of $T$ is nonzero after the standard matrix representation under the basis, after suitable composition of elementary matrix, we may assume that $a_{i,j}\ne 0$, then $(a_{i,j})^{-1}X_{i,i}TX_{j,j}$ sends $e_{j}$ to $e_{i}$ and is exactly $X_{j,i}$. Those $X_{i,j}$ constitute a basis for $L(V,V)$.